# Shutdown PC timer with warning

Tags: fedora, terminal, shutdown

I use Fedora 25 with Xfce. So I want to shutdown my PC using a timer. I use:

```
shutdown -P 30
```

But the PC will power off even if I am still working. How can I send a warning that the PC will be shutdown in 1 minute?

```
shutdown -P 30 and somethig else?
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shutdown -P +1
```

The above command will schedule a system shutdown for one minute from its execution, and will send a warning using `wall` to all terminals with a logged in shell.  To alter the message accompanying the warning, use:

```
shutdown -P +1 "Your Message Here"
```

The 30 you specified in your command schedules a shutdown (with periodic warnings) for 30 minutes from the time you execute the command; since you asked for a one minute delay in your question, that is what I used in the above examples.

`shutdown` will issue the warnings immediately upon execution, as well as at intervals approaching the scheduled shutdown (e. g. at one hour, five minutes, one minute, and immediately).